# Safely query size of element soon after inserting it to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

Is there an way (maybe an event?) to delay querying the height of element until all of the styles for it have been fully calculated, so that I know that it's height is calculated properly?

In my app I need to get the height of an element as soon as possible. I run that calculation soon after it's been inserted into DOM (using MutationObservers for detecing that). Still some (not all) of the results are incorrect - the height is different (higher) than what I see in the end in my browser. If I delay the calculation by 200ms using `setTimeout`, the results are corrent though.

Is there some cleaner solution to that, without using `setTimeout`? That one is a bit hacky (including the fact 200ms works in my browser doesn't mean that it'll work in all others and I can't increase it - I need to do that calculation as soon as possible).

Comment: doesn't it work with 0ms "delay" since this would be a standard way to wait for the dom to be updated?

Comment: Are you familiar with callback functions? Perhaps do the resizing as a callback at the very end.

Comment: @Kryptik It doesn't even work with 100ms.

Comment: @HC_ I know what a callback is, but at what event should it be invoked?

Comment: Probably you have to keep track of every image and external CSS file used in your page. Then you have to wait for every element to load and then wait one more tick. Probably you should embed every image in a data URI source.

Comment: @Kay How do I wait for images to be loaded? This element has children images, so that might be the problem.

Comment: if you're using jquery you could use `$(window).load( function(){ }`

Comment: I'm not using JQuery. All of that code is run after `DOMContextLoaded` event though.

Comment: posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `onload` event which fires after everything in the document has been completely loaded.

You can use it in your markup like this:

`<body onload="doStuffAfterEverythingIsLoaded()">...</body>`

or in your script:

`window.addEventListener("load", doStuffAfterEverythingIsLoaded);`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be what I'm looking for. I only wonder how to achieve similar effect for a single element (not the whole window). I mean how to detect moment when all the images being descendants of that element have been loaded. I could use `load` events for every single of these images and monitor that, right? But can I be sure that they will all get fired, even when the image is inaccessible over the web?

Comment: maybe you could preload the images, insert them when they are loaded (or not..) and wait for another load event after you inserted them into the dom (there a `setTimeout(function(){}, 0);` should be enough).

Comment: I think I'll handle it now. Thanks! @Kryptik